# SparkSQL in EMR to fetch Data from AWS Glue (Cross Account)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-iam, aws-glue, identity-management

I have a EMR cluster on which I am running a SparkSQL Job to fetch data from AWS Glue Catalogue (S3) and both are present in different accounts.

My query is something of the form:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee AS
SELECT
 pay.recordid,
        pay.employeeid,
        pay.amount,
        pay.paycode,
        pay.paydate,
        pay.paycycle,
        pay.updatetime
          FROM database.table pay 
WHERE 
pay.partition_0 in (var1)
and pay.partition_1 in (var2)
and pay.partition_2 in (var3)
and paycode = 'P1'
AND paycycle = 'M'
AND country = 'test'
AND paydate = ( SELECT DISTINCT paydate FROM default.table2
WHERE CURRENT_DATE < DATE(paydate) AND CURRENT_DATE > DATE(payperiodstart)
 AND paycycle = 'M')
 AND amount > 0;
```

In Glue Catalog settings I have to give permissions for Glue:CreateTable and Glue:DeleteTable as well. If I remove them then my query fails, so for creating views why are these 2 permissions required? Can I somehow remove these 2 permissions and run the query using only these permissions:
"glue:GetDatabase", "glue:GetUserDefinedFunctions", "glue:GetTable", "glue:GetPartitions"

I am saying this because it can pose a security risk. I am the owner of Glue Account and giving someone else read only permission so can't give DeleteTable or Create Table permission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide those permissions, since a view is behind the scenes just a regular Glue Table with special table properties:

[image]

Comment: Also with this permission there is a chance that if they run command for Deleting by original Glue table then that will be succeeded?

Comment: Yes, because replacing a view means essentially deleting the table. If you can do it without the ```OR REPLACE``` you shouldn't need the DeleteTable permission

Comment: 1. Basically if I run the command as is I need "CreateTable" as well as "DeleteTable"

2. If I run without OR REPLACE then "DeleteTable" i can remove but not "CreateTable" and everytime query runs multiple views will be created , is that so?

3. What if I use TEMPORARY view , any idea on that?

Comment: Yes, you need both.

Comment: I have updated my comment to have 3 points. Can you provide your valuable insight for the 3 points, that would be helpful.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2.  If you run without OR REPLACE, your query will fail, since a view with this name already exists. 3. Do you mean temporary cached views in the spark cluster itself?